# Splitting Cells in Excel with formulas

Tags: excel, split, formula, cells

I have a customer data sheet exported from QuickBooks to Excel. All of the info is in a single cell. I'm wanting to bring it out to new columns.
Data includes:  FirstName LastName 123 Address Road City,ST 29999 803-555-5555
All of the data is exactly as above. Can anybody help me with formulas to split all of it out into Firstname, Lastname, Address, City, State, Zip, and Phone? Thanks!

Comment: Does it have to be formula? Does a space always separate each column?

Comment: Some easy searches can show you information you. Like [this](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/splitting-data-into-multiple-columns-in-excel-2007.html) one. Try some things out and if it does not work as expected then update your question.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read this first: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Then do some your own work, more research, then fix your question accordingly.

Comment: VBA has a nice split function that you could use to split by space and store each piece as an array.

Answer (score 0):

This ends up a bit tricky as your address may have spaces in it but if your work from both ends in it works fine.  Assuming the data is in column A I would use these formulas and fill down.

B1

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1))
```

C1

```
=MID(A1,LEN(B1)+1,FIND(" ",MID(A1,LEN(B1)+1,99)))
```

D1

```
=MID(A1,LEN(B1)+LEN(C1)+1,LEN(A1)-LEN(B1)-LEN(C1)-LEN(E1)-LEN(F1)-2)
```

E1

```
=LEFT(RIGHT(A1,18),5)
```

F1

```
=RIGHT(A1,12)
```

Welcome to SE!  If this answers your question please mark it answered.